# How important are lookup tables?

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design

A lot of the applications I write make use of lookup tables, since that was just the way I was taught (normalization and such). The problem is that the queries I make are often more complicated because of this. They often look like this

*get all posts that are still open*

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status_id = (SELECT id FROM statuses WHERE name = 'open')"
```

Often times, the lookup tables themselves are very short. For instance, there may only be 3 or so different statuses. In this case, would it be okay to search for a certain type by using a constant or so in the application? Something like

*get all posts that are still open*

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status_id = ".Status::OPEN
```

Or, what if instead of using a foreign id, I set it as an enum and queried off of that?

Thanks.

Comment: If all your table stores are the various status values, that's not normalization. There should not be another table unless there is some other information to store dependent only on the status values. It's no different from having an 'age' column in a 'people' table, and deciding to create an 'ages' lookup table containing the numbers 1 through 150 -- and nobody would do that.

Comment: Okay, then a better example might be for a posts table and a categories lookup table.

Comment: @Dan What happens if I wanted to change the name of a status, add a new status, etc. Wouldnt that be much easier if I had the status names separate in a lookup table?

Comment: No, it's one UDPATE query to rename a status either way. Adding a status when you don't have a separate lookup table simply means using that status in a row for the first time, like inserting the first person with an age of 53.

Comment: I always preferred the lookup table as opposed to constants because why duplicate a varchar(20) in every row when you can use a 1 byte tinyint id.

Comment: @Dan. That example is fine.  But the question here is real lookup tables, which **is** normalisation; data Integrity; Referential Integrity, not some weird non-lookup table.  If data values "Open" are repeated in the data table, it i simply isn't normalised, and it is not a database.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA So if two person records have the same date-of-birth, repeating their DOB in their respective rows makes it not a database? Why do you decide some columns must be lookup tables and others not, when they are the same in terms of not having any other dependencies on those columns?

Comment: @Dan. No, I did not state that; that is your interpretation. There is not enough space in the comments to explain basic normalisation.  It is not a person decision or preference, it is a science. Ask that exact question as a new question, and I will answer it.

Comment: Just because something isn’t normalized to the n-th degree doesn’t mean it’s not a database.  It’s kinda terrifying you are a dba.

Comment: @MatthewWhited  1) There is no "nth degree", there is just Normalisation, or not.  2) Ok, you have to deal with **Update Anomalies** (duplicated data), which is the result of not-Normalised or "denormalised" (false because they did not Normalise in the fist place), and fiddle and change your "database" as an ongoing exercise.  In a Normalised database, we don't have those issues, we just go to the next project

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The answer depends a little if you are limited to freeware such as PostGreSQL (not fully SQL compliant), or if you are thinking about SQL (ie. SQL compliant) and large databases.

In SQL compliant, [Open Architecture](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Application%20Architecture/Open%20Architecture.pdf) databases, where there are many apps using one database, and many users using different report tools (not just the apps) to access the data, standards, normalisation, and open architecture requirements are important.

Despite the people who attempt to change the definition of "normalisation", etc. to suit their ever-changing purpose, Normalisation (the science) has not changed.

- if you have *data values* such as {`Open; Closed; etc`} repeated in data tables, that is **data duplication**, a simple Normalisation error:  if you those values change, you may have to update millions of rows, which is very limited design.

  - Such values should be Normalised into a Reference or Lookup table, with a short `CHAR(2)` PK:

    ```
    O  Open
    C  Closed
    U  [NotKnown]
    ```
  - The *data values* {`Open;Closed;etc`} are no longer duplicated in the millions of rows. It also saves space.
  - the second point is ease of change, if `Closed` were changed to `Expired`, again, one row needs to be changed, and that is reflected in the entire database; whereas in the un-normalised files, millions of rows need to be changed.
  - Adding new *data values*, eg. (`H,HalfOpen`) is then simply a matter of inserting one row.
- in [Open Architecture](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Application%20Architecture/Open%20Architecture.pdf) terms, the Lookup table is an ordinary table. It exists in the [SQL compliant] catalogue; as long as the `FOREIGN KEY` relation has been defined, the report tool can find that as well.
- `ENUM` is a Non-SQL, do not use it. In SQL the "enum" is a Lookup table.
- The next point relates to the meaningfulness of the key.

  - If the Key is meaningless to the user, fine, use an {`INT;BIGINT;GUID;etc`} or whatever is suitable; do not number them incrementally; allow "gaps".
  - But if the Key is meaningful to the user, do not use a meaningless number, use a meaningful Relational Key.
- Now some people will get in to tangents regarding the permanence of PKs.  That is a separate point.  Yes, of course, **always use a stable value for a PK** (not "immutable", because no such thing exists, and a system-generated key does not provide row uniqueness).

  - {`M,F`} are unlikely to change
  - if you have used {`0,1,2,4,6`}, well don't change it, why would you want to.  Those values were supposed to be meaningless, remember, only a meaningful Key need to be changed.
  - if you do use meaningful keys, use short alphabetic codes, that developers can readily understand (and infer the long description from).  You will appreciate this only when you code `SELECT` and realise you do not have to `JOIN` every Lookup table.  Power users too, appreciate it.
- Since PKs are stable, particularly in Lookup tables, you can safely code:

  `WHERE status_code = 'O'  -- Open`

  *You do not have to* `JOIN` *the Lookup table and obtain the* data value `Open`, *as a developer, you are supposed to know what the Lookup PKs mean.*

Last, if the database were large, and supported BI or DSS or OLAP functions in addition to OLTP (as properly Normalised databases can), then the Lookup table is actually a Dimension or Vector, in **Dimension-Fact** analyses.  If it was not there, then it would have to be added in, to satisfy the requirements of that software, before such analyses can be mounted.

- If you do that to your database from the outset, you will not have to upgrade it (and the code) later.

#### Your Example

SQL is a low-level language, thus it is cumbersome, especially when it comes to `JOINs`.  That is what we have, so we need to just accept the encumbrance and deal with it.  Your example code is fine. But simpler forms can do the same thing.

A report tool would generate:

```sql
SELECT p.*,
       s.name
    FROM posts  p, 
         status s
    WHERE p.status_id = s.status_id 
    AND   p.status_id = 'O'
```

#### Another Exaple

For banking systems, where we use short codes which are meaningful (since they are meaningful, we do not change them with the seasons, we just add to them), given a Lookup table such as (carefully chosen, similar to ISO Country Codes):
`Eq   Equity
EqCS Equity/Common Share
OTC  OverTheCounter
OF   OTC/Future`

Code such as this is common:

`WHERE InstrumentTypeCode LIKE "Eq%"`

And the users of the GUI would choose the value from a drop-down that displays
{`Equity/Common Share;Over The Counter`},
not {`Eq;OTC;OF`}, not {`M;F;U`}.
Without a lookup table, you can't do that, either in the apps, or in the report tool.

Comment: Thats exactly that I thought, since thats the way I was taught. I was just trying to see if there were any easier ways to handle the queries. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  At least we *had* science teachers.  These days there are many doing technical jobs, who never had teachers; they learn as they go. They have no higher authority, and they are frightened by anything that is different to what they have implemented, and argue with the science.  You have to be careful who you ask questions from.

Comment: "if you have 'Open' and 'Closed' repeated in data tables, that is a simple Normalisation error." I don't understand what you're saying here. Can you unpack that a little bit?

Comment: @CatCall. Sure. Normalisation is a large subject. The comments are a restrictive format. I don't know where to stat with you. Could you open a new question so that I can answer fully.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - Perhaps you have such ardent followers because, some of us, who lack the benefit of the CS education you espouse, are doing our level best to get what we can!!  ;-). For me, returning to school is not an option, and this is essentially a hobby for me. I am always seeking the type of feedback folks such as yourself provide. It is too easy to pick up bad info these days. While I am glad programming tools have become more accessible for the "rest of us", I am also glad there are those out there willing to let us hijack your grad degrees! Thanks . . .

Comment: @XIV. Glad to be of service, my explanations are for seekers like you. The misinformers are common, but here they have "rep" and attack the truth. This despite the FAQ encouraging us to correct misinformation.

Comment: "M" and "F" are unlikely to change - Depends on your data.  There do exist "beings" of many variety (even human) that are neither male nor female and sometimes both.  Of course, in the human case, they usually associate with and report a single gender.  The safe bet is to normalize all the way down but as the OP suggests it can be a pain.

Comment: Emphasis on: "if you have "Open" and "Closed" repeated in data tables, that is a simple Normalisation error. If you change those values you may have to update millions of rows, which is very limited design. "

Comment: @JRLawhorne  1) No. Male/Female is defined in the chromosomes, at the cell level: every cell in a body in either Male xor Female. 2) Sure, there are very rare occurrences of deformities (a woman with two wombs; a man with out genitals; etc), but that does not change the fact that every cell in their body is Male xor Female.  3) The occurrences in the tiny corners of the Bell curve do not change the Bell curve.

Answer (score 1):

For look-up tables I use a sensible primary key -- usually just a CHAR(1) that makes sense in the domain with an additional Title (VARCHAR) field. This can maintain relationship enforcement while "keeping the SQL simple". The key to remember here is the look-up table does *not "contain data"*. It contains *identities*. Some other identities might be time-zone names or assigned [IOC country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IOC_country_codes).

For instance gender:

```
ID Label
M  Male
F  Female
N  Neutral
```

```
select * from people where gender = 'M'
```

Alternatively, an ORM could be used and manual SQL generation might never have to be done -- in this case the standard "int" surrogate key approach is fine because something else deals with it :-)

Happy coding.

Comment: In this case, this makes sense. What about when its not that simple. For instance, say you have a lookup table of categories with 30 different categories. What sensible primary keys could you think of for each that wouldnt cause confusion/conflict in the future?

Comment: Wrote the last comment before you added the ORM part. So I guess what you're saying is theres no need for the extra constants in the application?

Comment: @DBuelz I updated my post again to mention "data-vs-identities". Also the key doesn't have to be limited to just CHAR(1) but if it grow past say, CHAR(3) or the values are really contrived then I wonder if it's really a "lookup" table and not better suited as another relational data-table. Constants in the application will exist at some level and syncing is always a requirement. The additional column has the added-benefit of "adding implicit documentation". However it will generally fail to use this approach (alone) for internationalization.

Comment: @DBuelz Consider a look-up table for years where the natural PK might be the year number itself. The year is still an *identity* that represents itself.

Comment: I think I understand what your saying. I suppose I was a little confused as to what a lookup table was exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function for each lookup.
There is no easy way. You want performance and query simplicity. Ensure the following is maintained. You could create a SP_TestAppEnums to compare existing lookup values against the function and look for out of sync/zero returned.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Enum_Post](@postname varchar(10))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @postId int
SET @postId =
CASE @postname
WHEN 'Open' THEN 1
WHEN 'Closed' THEN 2
END

RETURN @postId
END
GO

/* Calling the function */
SELECT dbo.Enum_Post('Open')
SELECT dbo.Enum_Post('Closed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is: do you need to include the lookup tables (domain tables 'round my neck of the woods) in your queries? Presumably, these sorts of tables are usually

- pretty static in nature — the domain might get extended, but it probably won't get shortened.
- their primary key values are pretty unlikely to change as well (e.g., the status_id for a status of 'open' is unlikely to suddenly get changed to something other than what it was created as).

If the above assumptions are correct, there's no real need to add all those extra tables to your joins just so your where clause can use a friend name instead of an id value. Just filter on status_id directly where you need to. I'd suspect the non-key attribute in the where clause ('name' in your example above)  is more likely to get changes than the key attribute ('name' in your example above): you're more protected by referencing the desire key value(s) of the domain table in your join.

Domain tables serve

- to limit the domain of the variable via a foreign key relationship,
- to allow the domain to be expanded by adding data to the domain table,
- to populate UI controls and the like with user-friendly information,

Naturally, you'd need to suck domain tables into your queries where you you actually required the non-key attributes from the domain table (e.g., descriptive name of the value).

YMMV: a lot depends on context and the nature of the problem space.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "whatever makes sense".

lookup tables involve joins or subqueries which are not always efficient. I make use of enums a lot to do this job. its efficient and fast

Comment: While terse, this is actually a good answer.  The only correct answers to the question "How important are lookup tables?" are those that effectively equate to an answer of "it depends".

Answer (score 0):

**The commenters have convinced me of the error of my ways. This answer and the discussion that went along with it, however, remain here for reference.**

I think a constant is appropriate here, and a database table is not. As you design your application, you expect that table of statuses to never, ever change, since your application has hard-coded into it what those statuses mean, anyway. The point of a database is that the data within it *will* change. There are cases where the lines are fuzzy (e.g. "this data might change every few months or so…"), but this is not one of the fuzzy cases.

Statuses are a part of your application's logic; use constants to define them within the application. It's not only more strictly organized that way, but it will also allow your database interactions to be significantly speedier.

Comment: Very true, this seems like a perfect use of constants.

Comment: What if I did both? What if I had the extra table solely for documenting reasons?

Comment: -1 A look-up table *is* a set of constants (surrogate or natural PK aside). The difference is they are *encoded into the database* and thus *maintain integrity* (with the correct DDL). The database and codebase need to work together in-step. Using constants is not orthogonal to a look-up table. They are re-enforcing.

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed to be 100% static, not even primary keys.  If you use referential integrity & create a table to store the values for lookup, the system is better set to adjust to changes if they happen.  If they never happen, big deal -- it's a HUGE PITA to alter data.

Comment: @pst That is exactly what I thought, and thus never used constants.

Comment: @BDuelz: well, maybe I'm not fully understanding your scenario. It sounds like statuses like "open" and "closed" fundamentally figure into your application's inner workings, rather than just being generic categories. Is there anything particularly special about a ticket being open? If not, then a table is appropriate.

Comment: @Matchu.  Exactly the same as pst.  You notion of change is unusual.  There is nothing fuzzy in databases, maybe in uncontrolled, unconstrained filing systems.

Comment: @Performance: Got it. My general design pattern has considered application logic and the database to have separate roles, but I see some good reasons here to reconsider that practice. I'll leave this answer here as an example of something incorrect :)

Answer (score 0):

Where possible (and It is not always . . .), I use this rule of thumb: If I need to hard-code a value into my application (vs. let it remain a record in the database), and also store that vlue in my database, then something is amiss with my design. It's not ALWAYS true, but basically, whatever the value in question is, it either represents a piece of DATA, or a peice of PROGRAM LOGIC. It is a rare case that it is both.

NOT that you won't find yourself discovering which one it is halfway into the project. But as the others said above, there can be trade-offs either way. Just as we don't always acheive "perfect" normalization in a database design (for reason of performance, or simply because you CAN take thngs too far in pursuit of acedemic perfection . . .), we may make some concious choices about where we locate our "look-up" values.

Personally, though, I try to stand on my rule above. It is either DATA, or PROGRAM LOGIC, and rarely both. If it ends up as (or IN) a record in the databse, I try to keep it out of the Application code (except, of course, to retrieve it from the database . . .). If it is hardcoded in my application, I try to keep it out of my database.

In cases where I can't observe this rule, I DOCUMENT THE CODE with my reasoning, so three years later, some poor soul will be able to ficure out how it broke, if that happens.

Comment: Recently I wrote a small newsletter app, where each newsletter had a status of either "canceled", "error", "sent", etc. In the model, I set constants for each status to assist with the logic. For instance: if($something_went_wrong) $newsletter->status = Newsletter::ERROR; $newsletter->save()...as you can see, I used an ORM