# AdventureWorks have Insert/Update/Delete anomalies?

Tags: database-design, normalization

AdventureWorks tables have Insert/Update/Delete anomalies. Isn't that considered bad design?

Let's take for example following table.

```
Sales.SalesReason(SalesReasonID, Name, ReasonType, ModifiedDate)
```

where ReasonType is of type nvarchar(50)

Shouldn't we have another table for ReasonType so the model would look like this:

```
SalesReason(SalesReasonID, Name, ReasonTypeId, ModifiedDate)  
ReasonType(ReasonTypeId, Name)
```

This way when doing update of name of ReasonType the change should be done only on one record (prevent update anomaly). Also, it will prevent delete/insert anomalies by keeping available types in db disregarding of whether there are actual data related to them.

Can I have your thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing ReasonType to another table wouldn't improve anything. Presumably you would still have one ReasonTypeId per ReasonType so you still have the same potential number of updates to do. I guess you are assuming that you would need to update ReasonTypeId less frequently than ReasonType. Without knowing more about the business requirements that's just a possibility but it doesn't have anything to do with solving the type of "update anomaly" that database design theory is usually concerned with.

Consider the table from a normalization theory point of view. If the dependencies are:

```
{SalesReasonID}->{Name}
{SalesReasonID}->{ReasonType}
{SalesReasonID}->{ModifiedDate}
```

and if SalesReasonID is the only key then the table is already in Fifth Normal Form. So it doesn't require any further decomposition.

[The Relational Database Dictionary](http://www.apress.com/9781430210412) has this to say about the term "update anomaly":

> A somewhat old fashioned term, never very precisely defined, for the
>   kind of thing that can go wrong in a less than fully normalized
>   database

Carlo Zaniolo says:

> no clear-cut description of anomalies can be given without knowing the
>   operations envisioned by the user

(ACM Transactions on Database Systems, Vol. 6, No. 1, March 1981)

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I'm not sure you've understand me correctly, probably I wasn't very clear. Let's take this data for example:
SalesReason:
`(1,"Name1", "Some Reason", 1/1/2001),
(2,"Name2", "Some Reason", 6/5/2001),
(3,"Name3", "Some other reason", 7/6/2001),
(4,"Name4", "Best Reason", 8/9/2001)`

Comment: So, I want to change name of "Some Reason" to "Reason with a brand new name". In order to do it I have to do the update on two rows. This is simple example, but lets say I have other tables that have ReasonType column. If i had it like a foreign key, all I would have to do is to update name on that single record on ReasonType table.
Furthermore, just by looking at database, I don't realy know what are all available and possible reason types.
What's your opinion on this?

Comment: Just found one topic that supports statement that AdventureWork have anomalies, please take a look: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824024/how-important-are-lookup-tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824024/how-important-are-lookup-tables)

Comment: @Poke, I don't think the question of whether these are "anomalies" is interesting or important (see my edited answer). Given the "obvious" set of dependencies I have mentioned I think we can say that the SalesReason table is already in 5NF. That doesn't mean that further possibly desirable improvements can't be made.

Comment: I understand know what you are saying, thanks. One last thing, if for example, the business requirements are such that ReasonType is a set of well known and predefined values, would then make sense to create a separate reference table?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the set of values is known at design time then they can just as well be defined by a CHECK constraint on the ReasonType column.