# Best pratice to design this: enum in c# or separate database table

Tags: c#, database-design, database-schema

i am creating records in a table and one column is called TYPE. I am programmatically looping through an enum in c# and creating this rows. The enum contains types of things for example

- car
- plane
- boat
- ...

An Important thing is, that this types are bound to a logic. One my question:

Should i put these types in the enum as described above or would it be better to put these in a separate table to have a normalize form.

What would you prefer?

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824024/how-important-are-lookup-tables I would add that it is usually much easier to alter values in a lookup table in the db than in the application once everything is in production. To alter the enum you would need to re-deploy the app.

Comment: Thanks wooters! The link helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on two things:

- Are values unstable?<sup>1</sup>
- Do you need to attach additional information?<sup>2</sup>

If the answer to any of the above questions is "yes", then using a dedicated lookup table is probably a good idea. Otherwise, constant enum values<sup>3</sup> that are well-known and well-documented throughout the system are OK.

The point is: don't use lookup tables blindly, as is sometimes suggested. They certainly have their place, but there are also cases where they should *not* be used.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Existing value can change or be deleted, or new values can be added.*

*<sup>2</sup> Such as human-readable (and potentially localizable) name or description, or some way to drive the logic from the contents of the database as opposed to hard-coding.*

*<sup>3</sup> Usually simple integers. If you find yourself needing to use strings, that probably means you should have answered "yes" to question (2).*

Comment: The values are stable and no other information is needed. Programmatically i would need to write for both solutions (enum, lookup) for each value the separate logic. This means: if value = cars then ... else if value = planes then ... etc. I think in this case it makes no difference!?

Comment: @BOGLabs Do you need to show "car", "plane" (etc.) in the UI?

Comment: Yes i do. I need to provide this in a dropdown list and in a grid.

Comment: @BOGLabs Then it looks like you'd want to keep user-readable descriptions of these values in a lookup table.